# PHP Get one index and item of an array

Tags: php, arrays, random, indexing

I have the below function which will ask one of the questions of the array by random, and the answer must be sent to the database along with the index number of the asked question to be saved and used again on an event like password recovery etc...

My problem is I havent been able to find a method or option to use for getting both the index number and the question to be asked together.

I have tried the key, search_array and other ways but to no avail yet.

Please help

Thanks

```
 <?php
    function secQ(){
        $questions = array();
        $questions[0] = "first question";
        $questions[1] = "second question";
        $questions[2] = "third question";
        $questions[3] = "fourth question";
        $questions[4] = "fifth qestion";
        $questions[5] = "sixth question";
        $rand_keys = array_rand($questions, 2);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: you are not returning anything from the function

Comment: Good Call on that  Mawia HL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to return the key and question in an array to the caller.

```
<?php
function secQ(){
    $questions = array();
    $questions[0] = "first question";
    $questions[1] = "second question";
    $questions[2] = "third question";
    $questions[3] = "fourth question";
    $questions[4] = "fifth qestion";
    $questions[5] = "sixth question";

    $rand_key = array_rand($questions, 1);

    return array($rand_key, $questions[$rand_key]);
}

$q = secQ();
echo 'key is ' . $q[0];
echo 'question is ' . $q[1];
?>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you very much,now I must get the key and save in the database for when it is needed.

Comment: I added the script and it worked perfectly, although sometimes the key for the question which is saved in the database is not the one I see in the form, I will edit my question here with your answer, thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I am afraid you should not do that. The original question is answered and if others find this question in a search this answer wont match your second question. Which is the point of this site i.e. providing searchable questions with answers. I will rollback your question. Please ask another question, I will keep an eye out for it.

Comment: Oh sorry I didnt reallise that, thanks for the heads up, I will write another one, Thanks again.

Comment: The question is HERE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377825/php-random-array-with-key

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do this manually. Below is a generic function which should work for any input array.

First of all generate a random number based on the size of the array, then return the key and value which correspond to that number. Note: I'm doing this to allow the method to work with associative arrays.

```
function randomKeyValueFromArray($array) {
         $randomKey = rand(0,count($array));
         return [ array_keys($array)[$randomKey], array_values($array)[$randomKey] ];

}
```

How to use:

```
$questions = array();
$questions[0] = "first question";
$questions[1] = "second question";
$questions[2] = "third question";
$questions[3] = "fourth question";
$questions[4] = "fifth qestion";
$questions[5] = "sixth question";

$randomQuestion = randomKeyValueFromArray($questions);

$questionKey = $randomQuestion[0];
$questionValue = $randomQuestion[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found out this solution

```
<?php
function secQ()
{
    $questions = [
        "first question",
        "second question",
        "third question",
        "fourth question",
        "fifth qestion",
        "sixth question",
    ];

    $keys = array_keys($questions);

    $rand_keys = array_rand($keys, 2);

    $result = array();
    foreach ($rand_keys as $key) {
        $result[$key] = $questions[$key];
    }
    return $result;
}

var_dump(secQ());
```

First result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(14) "first question"
  [1]=> string(15) "second question"
}
```

Second result:

```
array(2) {
  [4]=>string(13) "fifth qestion"
  [5]=>string(14) "sixth question"
}
```