# PHP, Random array with key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the below array which generates a random question with its key for a form.

I save the key in my database for later use, eg Password recovery etc...

The problem is each time the question is asked the key which is saved in the database is mostly not the one for the asked question.

Here is my insert.php for saving the key (secQ):

All the connections and validations which work correctly...

```
<?php
    include("questions.php");
    $dbh= $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (secQ ) values (?)");
    $dbh->bindParam(1, $secQ );
    $dbh->execute();
?>
```

And this is my questions.php:

```
<?php
    function secQ(){
        $questions = array();

        $questions[0] = "1";
        $questions[1] = "2";
        $questions[2] = "3";
        $questions[3] = "4";
        $questions[4] = "5";

        $rand_key = array_rand($questions, 1);
        return array($rand_key, $questions[$rand_key]);
     }
    $q = secQ();
    $secQ = $q[0];
    $question = $q[1];
 ?>
```

I guess this is due to the fact that before secQ is inserted into the database 
there is the include("questions.php"); which it may again generate a different key randomly other than the askedquestion in the form.

Thanks a looot

Comment: `$dbh` !== `$stmt`

Comment: Sorry thats a mistake but it works correctly in the actual code , I will edit that

Comment: this code and the form is all in the same file?

Comment: @CJNimes, No form.php seperate,insert.php seperate and questions.php also seperate, no reference for the secQ in the form, as it was not needed to my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a good solution:

We can use sessions to communicate between the php files as follows:

in the insert.php:

```
$secQ = $_SESSION['secQ'];
```

in the questions.php:

```
$_SESSION['secQ'] = $secQ;
```

This works, but Im concerned about the security of this method as I start the session for the insert.php right before inserting the data into the database.

Any Comments on this would help a lot, thank you.